# Electromagnetic Light and Radio Pulses in Combination against Skin Conditions

Tags: dermatology, acne

Reading up on recent developments in the treatments for [Hidradenitis suppurativa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidradenitis_suppurativa) I came across a brand new option. Τhat option, if true, would by absolutely sensational on several fronts:

The so called [lAight](https://lenicura.com/de/laight/) therapy ([English version of page](https://lenicura.com/laight/)): "Using a combination of intense light and radio wave pulses" (apparently no UV, no laser, and not for hair removal?) After initial skepticism about this seemingly commercial quackery, it was revealed that it was developed at or with [Mainz University](http://www.unimedizin-mainz.de/presse/pressemitteilungen/aktuellemitteilungen/newsdetail/article/neue-bestrahlungstherapie-gegen-akne-inversa.html) and apparently approved – officially as a [medical device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_device) under EU law – but it is not yet widespread.

On their marketing page they say that the treatment has the following effects:

- Antibacterial effect
- Reduction of sebum production
- Stimulation of blood circulation
- Stimulation of tissue regeneration
- Reduction of hair follicle blockage
- Anti-inflammatory

Given the hideous state of sufferers and the medical knowledge of this disease as well, I was looking for studies on this technique. Claims and praise for its effectiveness seem a bit over the top, indicating a very wide range of application, among them classical acne vulgaris and scars.

These studies seem to be non-existent? Where is the NICE-study? (NonInvasive Combination therapy in acnE inversa, 2014-2016) [note that the names for this condition AE and HS seem interchangeable or [a cultural matter]](https://www.aerzteblatt.de/archiv/29255/Acne-inversa)(g). How could this method be approved, be on the market since 2017, if the studies supporting it are apparently "one" and still not "in print"?

So the question is: I want to know how that is supposed to work. I presume in that study they explain some of that in theory and in their observed outcome. But I can not locate that study or [other studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5156664/)<sup>**1**</sup> going into the same direction.

---

1: Apart from those studies list at the bottom of the product page.

<sub>A little background on the development and approval is published in [Das unbekannte Leiden](https://www.freitag.de/autoren/alux/das-unbekannte-leiden). Gist: two medical outsiders had an idea, presented their case to the university for conducting a proper trial, and after still encouraging immediately founded a company to promote their product. Currently it seems that there is an astroturfing campaign or real general interest in the subject.
 Non-medical articles in German are numerous. Suspiciously so. By far not all of them quack. The procedure appears to gain traction with respectable dermatologists.</sub>

Comment: The nice study is awaiting publication. See bottom of https://lenicura.com/laight/

Comment: @GrahamChiu That I know and hopefully expressed above. But often accepted for print articles appear somewhere else – the approval paper is somewhere (less blurred than on their site etc) – Data on this disease is so incomplete and sometimes outright contradictory with what I've seen and heard and read. – Especially the circumstantial papers linked by themselves seem to be in conflict with some of their statements available (laser or not, hair removal or not / radio?, wavelengths used?). So anything more for principles and insights helps. Maybe this is premature, you need not answer tonite.

Comment: The only breakthrough I was aware of was the utility of anti-tnf agents.

Comment: Five years later there are now published studies on this technology. See [this article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31609667/) and similar articles listed below.